# Rails No route matches, on Polymorphic new action test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, polymorphic-associations

This is my first time with polymorphic associations, so the error is probably something trivial.

From the start, models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment_owner, polymorphic: true 
end

class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :comment_owner
end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :announcements do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Comment controller new action:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_comment_owner

  def new
    @comment = @comment_owner.comments.new
  end

  private

  def find_comment_owner
    # Switch comment_owner_string into constant
    @klass = params[:comment_owner_type].capitalize.constantize
    @comment_owner = @klass.find(params[:comment_owner_id])
  end
end
```

And finally test:

```
  describe 'New action test' do
    let(:dummy_post) do
      create(:announcement)
    end
    before :each do
      get :new, comment_owner_id: dummy_post.id, comment_owner_type: dummy_post.class.name
    end

    it 'return redirect http status' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
```

And my error:

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"new", :comment_owner_id=>"27", :comment_owner_type=>"Announcement", :controller=>"comments"}
```

My thoughts,Routes should be [fine](http://thelazylog.com/posts/polymorphic-routes-in-rails), the Action is build upon this [tutorial](http://pathfindersoftware.com/2008/07/drying-up-rails-controllers-polymorphic-and-super-controllers/), params for comment_owner should have no meaning at this time, since it can`t find the new action in the comments controller.

Comment: You can check you generated route form `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`

Comment: `new_announcement_comment_path  GET  /announcements/:announcement_id/comments/new(.:format)  comments#new ` This is my new announcement comment route

Comment: Do you use this link? what actually you are wanting?

Comment: My problem is with the test not working correct. At The moment I don’t use this link I want to test comments actions first. And when I try to test simple new action from comments controller I get error

Comment: I think you need to use the polymorphic association name and let Rails handle matching the action. Try `get :new, comment_owner: dummy_post`

Comment: Nope, I get `Failure/Error: get :new, comment_owner: dummy_post
     
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"new", :comment_owner=>"27", :controller=>"comments" }` error